# How to make remove_node function in C list

Tags: c, list

I am trying to make a remove_node in my C list but everytime while I am trying to solve this problem my function mess up my whole list and I don't know how to do it.

Here is the source code:

```
struct lista
{
    int data;
    struct lista *next;
};

struct listaWsk
{
    struct lista *head,*tail;
};

void create(struct listaWsk *lista, int data)
{
    struct lista *new = malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        new ->data = data;
        new ->next = NULL;
        lista ->head = new;
        lista ->tail = new;
    }
}

void print_list(struct listaWsk lista)
{
    while(lista.head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ",lista.head->data);
        lista.head=lista.head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void addhead(struct listaWsk *lista, int data)
{
    struct lista *new = malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        new ->data = data;
        new ->next = lista->head;
        lista ->head = new;
    }
}

void addtail(struct listaWsk *lista, int data)
{
    struct lista *new = malloc(sizeof(struct lista));
    if(new != NULL)
    {
        new ->data = data;
        new ->next = NULL;
        lista ->tail ->next = new;
        lista -> tail = new;
    }
}

struct lista *find_prev(struct listaWsk lista, int data)
{
    struct lista *prev;
    if(lista.head->data != data && lista.head != NULL)
    {
    while(lista.head->data != data)
    {
        prev = lista.head;
        lista.head = lista.head->next;
    }
    return prev;
    }
}

void remove_node(struct listaWsk *lista, int data) //remove_node function
{
    struct listaWsk *tmp = lista;
    if(lista->head->data != data && lista->head != NULL)
    {
    while(tmp ->head->next->data != data)
        {
            tmp -> head = tmp -> head->next;
        }
        tmp -> head -> next = tmp -> head ->next->next;    

        }
}

int main()
{
    struct listaWsk lista;
    create(&lista,1);
    addhead(&lista,7);
    addtail(&lista,10);
    print_list(lista);
    remove_node(&lista,10);
    print_list(lista);
}
```

Output:

```
7 1 10
1 (after remove_node)
```

I guess it happens because of while loop in remove_node but I have no idea how should I do it.

Comment: Make sure your code can be compiled without warnings. Your function `find_prev` does not always return a value. In all functions that contain a condition `if(lista.head->data != data && lista.head != NULL)`, the check for `NULL` must be done before dereferencing the pointer. Please [edit] your question and add more detail. Show the expected output in addition to the actual output. Does the problem also occur when you remove one of the other values?

Comment: Both functions `find_prev` and `remove_node` do nothing if `(lista.head->data != data && lista.head != NULL)` is not true. What should happen in the other cases? I think that `lista.head == NULL` and `lista.head->data == data` must be handled differently, so it might be better to split the combined `if` statements into two and add `else` branches where necessary. Try to explain your `remove_node` function to yourself and, if this does not help to find the problem, to us in the question. Then it is easier to point out what's wrong. Your loops need an additional condition for "value not found".

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, "removal from list" procedure should:

1. Find node to remove (and do no further action if not found).
2. Remove node from list (i.e. adjust next pointer of the previous node, if it exists).
3. Free memory possesed by a removed node.
4. Take care of updating head and tail if element was first or last in the list or single one.

Existing function only attempts to do (1) and (2) but in a wrong way. Finding node should traverse from the head of list and result found node and previous node, if appropriate node ever exists.

Hope this helps to implement proper logic.
Sorry, but no ready code from me - I guess it's your homework to write the code.

Comment: Did you look at the code? The title may be misleading, but the code contains a `remove_node` function which does not seem to work as expected.

Comment: Yes, I have seen the code. The function as it currently is does not do the proper thing. So I've tried to explain what it should do. But I say I won't write the code, I think in this case it should be up to person who asks this.

Comment: I think a good answer should point out what's wrong with the existing function, e.g. tell which points of your general description are or are not or not correctly implemented.

Comment: ok, I have updated a bit my answer.